Can ring signatures be considered as non interactive set membership proofs?
Can ring signatures be considered as non interactive set membership proofs?
For example, if the message msg is set to null, can the ring signature scheme proposed by Rivest et al. be regarded as a non interactive set membership proof scheme that satisfies zero knowledge and knowledge soundness?

Yes, the ring signature scheme can be regarded as a membership proof. If the underlying proof system features non-interactive, soundness, and zero-knowledge, then it can meet your mentioned properties.
